# Div contents disappears when animating slide menu

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have added a custom menu that slides left to right. The mechanism works by first. Collapsing the menu and the width is toggled from there. The width of the main content with class .inner is reduced to 30% width. I was wondering if someone could either show me a better way to do this in general or show me how to fix the contents of the .inner div to not temporarily disappear. Site is [Here](http://stanprofile.000webhostapp.com/Updated)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html  lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale=1>
    <link rel="icon" href="Images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@300&family=Montserrat:wght@100&family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var swap;
        swap = 0;
  $(".outer").animate({width: 'toggle'},{duration:1,queue:false}); 
    
 
  $(".ham").on("click", function() {
      $(".outer").animate({width: 'toggle'},{duration:500,queue:false});

      
      if(swap === 0){
    $(".inner").css('overflow','hidden');
          $(".inner").animate({width: '30%'}, {duration:500,queue:false});
      
          swap = 1;
      } else{
    $(".inner").css('overflow','visible');
          $(".inner").animate({width: '100%'}, {duration:500,queue:false});
          
          swap = 0;
      }
 
 
    
  return false;
 
    
});
return false;
});
</script>
    <title>Stanley's Personal Site</title>

  </head>

  <body>
      <div  class="outer"><p class="para">stuff here</p></div>
      <div class = "inner" >
    <div id="navBar">
        <img class="ham" src="Images/Ham.png" alt=hamburger" />
    <img class="propic"  style="float:left; margin-top:21px;" src="Images/cloud.png" alt="cloud" />
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="top">

    <img class="top-cloud" src="Images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-image">
    <h1> I am Stanley</h1>
    <p>a <span class="pro">pro</span>grammer</p>
    <img class="bottom-cloud" src="Images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-image">
    <img class ="mountainImg" src="Images/mountain.png" alt="Moutain-img">
    </div>

    <div class="middle">
      <div class="profile">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <h2>Hello.</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitae volutpat, dui conubia, dolor urna. Non auctor, montes nulla distinctio.</p>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="skills">
        <h2>My Skills.</h2>
        <div class="skill-row">
          <img class="computer" src="Images/computer.png" alt="computer">
          <h3>Lorem & Ipsum</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quis in duis, iaculis id felis. Consectetuer vestibulum, nunc urna lectus, erat ligula. Hendrerit nam, lectus ante, ut lorem eros.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skill-row">
          <img class="chillies" src="Images/chillies.png" alt="chillies">
          <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mauris sed consectetuer. Etiam et eu, bibendum interdum, lacus quis mauris. Curabitur wisi, quisque vel eu, rutrum nam.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="bottom-h2">
      <div class="contact-me">
        <h2 class="bottom-h2">Get In Touch</h2>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, non elit.</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in quis, aenean amet. Phasellus sodales, tellus donec dui, ornare erat.</p>
        <a class="btn" href="mailto:name@email.com">CONTACT ME</a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="bottom">
      <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/">LinkedIn</a>
      <a class="footer-link" href="https://twitter.com/">Twitter</a>
      <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.appbrewery.co/">Website</a>
      <p>© 2018 Name Surname.</p>
    </div>


    </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>

html,body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}
h1{
margin-top:0;
font-family: 'Sacramento',cursive;
}
h2,h3{
  font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
}
.top{
  background:#E4F9F5;
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top:100px;
}
.top-cloud{
  position:absolute;
  right:300px;
  top:50px;
}
.bottom-cloud{
  position:absolute;
  left:300px;
  bottom:300px;
}
#navBar{
  color:#ebebeb;
  height:70px;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:70px;
  margin:0;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#navBar ul{
  
  padding:0;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:0;
  margin-left:-150px;
}

#navBar ul li {
  display:inline-block;
 height:90px;
font-size:1rem;

 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#navBar ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:1rem;
  border-left:1px solid #ebebeb;
border-right:1px solid #dcdcdc;
color:#707070;
display:inline-block;
}

#navBar ul li:hover{
  background: rgba(230,230,230,255);
  color:#707070;


}

.skill-row{
  width:50%;
  margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
  text-align: left;
}

.chillies{
  float:right;
  margin-left:30px;
  clear:left;
  width:25%;

}
.computer
{
  width:25%;
  float:left;
  clear:right;
  margin-right:30px;
   border-radius: 50%;
}

.middle{
  text-align: center;
}

.ham{
    float:left;
    display:none;
    margin-top:25px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}

.bottom{
  background-color: #0C3BAA;
text-align: center;
color:#a0a0a0;
}

.bottom a, .contact-me a{
    color:#a0a0a0;
}

img{
  display:inline-block;
}

.para{
    display:none;
}

.pro{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.contact-me{
  background-color: #0C3BAA;
  color:#a0a0a0;
}

.inner{
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:visible;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

.bottom-h2{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.propic{
    
}

    
    .outer{
        display:inline-block;
        width:70%;
        height:100%;
        min-height:100%;
  background: #f8f8ff;
  box-shadow: 8px 0px 8px -4px #000;
    }
    



@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #navBar ul {
        display:none;
    }
    
    .mountainImg{
        width:50%;
    }
    .bottom-cloud{
        display:none;
    }
    
    .ham{
        display:inline;
    }

    .propic{
        display:none;
    }
    .outer{
        float:left;
  
        
    }
    
.para{
    display:block;
}
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Show some code and it'll be a lot easier to provide help. Also that link is throwing a phishing warning.

Comment: Added the code. Sorry it's in one block